# How can I show that $2 < 1/a + 1/b <e$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

It is given that $b \ln a - a \ln b = a - b$  for $a>0 , b>0 , a \ne b$

I need to show that $$2< 1/a + 1/b < e.$$

I am able to apply laws of logs and therefore introduce $e $ in the expression, but then how do I get $(a+b)/ab$?

Comment: yes,  agreed  a≠b.

Comment: Possible simplification: if we set $\alpha = ea$ and $\beta = eb$, then the given equation becomes $\alpha/\ln\alpha = \beta/\ln\beta$ and one must show $2/e<1/\alpha+1/\beta<1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us write $x:=a/b$. Then the original condition may be written
$$\ln a=\frac{x\ln x}{x-1}-1.$$
We are asked to find the bounds of
$$y:=\frac1a+\frac1b=(1+x)\exp\left(\frac{x\ln x}{1-x}+1\right),$$
where $x>0$ and $x\neq1$. The discontinuity in $y$ at $x=1$ is removable because $\lim_{x\to1-}y=\lim_{x\to1+}y=2$. Also, $\lim_{x\to0+}y=\lim_{x\to\infty}y=\mathrm e$. To find the in-range minimum of $y$, differentiate to get
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{2-2x+(1+x)\ln x}{(1-x)^2}\exp\left(\frac{x\ln x}{1-x}+1\right).$$
This is zero if
$$z:=\ln x-2+\frac4{1+x}=0.$$
To see when this happens, consider the gradient
$$\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{(1-x)^2}{x(1+x)^2}.$$
This is positive for $x>0$ except at $x=1$, where $z=0$. Hence there is just one minimum for $y$: namely $y=2$ when $x=1$. It follows that $$2<\frac1a+\frac1b<\mathrm e.$$

**Edit:** $\;$To see that $y\to\mathrm e$ as $x\to\infty$, let $t:=\ln x$. Then
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}y=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left[(1+\mathrm e^t)\exp\left(\frac{t\mathrm e^t}{1-\mathrm e^t}+1\right)\right]\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

$$=\lim_{t\to\infty}\left[\exp\left(1-\frac t{1-\mathrm e^{-t}}\right)+\exp\left(1-\frac t{\mathrm e^t-1}\right)\right]$$
$$=\mathrm e.$$

Comment: Very helpful John: Check if there is  a typo in the first line (equation).

Comment: @WaitaraMburu : I have checked it, and it looks OK. Note that the RHS of the first displayed equation is minus the argument of the exponential in the second one. I did correct a spelling typo in line $-3$, though.$\qquad$ I am sorry that this interesting question was closed. Any question on this site risks being closed, regardless of its mathematical appeal, unless the OP details how and why he came to post it, along with his useless attempts to solve it and efforts to find a solution elsewhere. To get it reopened, and perhaps receive more answers, I suggest editing it accordingly.

Comment: Agreed, my omission: Now John the second limit for y approaching e , when x approaches infinity is the only sticking point, could you shed some light?

Comment: @WaitaraMburu : See my edit.

Comment: Very helpful John! Use of  t = ln x makes it looks more  accessible for all!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: Firstly, taking $x=1/a$ , $y=1/b$ so you have $$\frac{y\ln y-x\ln x}{y-x} =1$$
and you have to prove $2< x+y<e$. In order to prove that, you will prove the following inequality:
$$\ln(x+y)<\frac{y\ln y-x\ln x}{y-x} < \ln\left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right)+1$$

Answer (score 0):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}\def\Catalan{\mathsf{Catalan}}$

> Given that \begin{align}b \ln a - a \ln b = a - b \quad\text{for } a>0, b>0, a\ne b \tag{1}\label{1}\end{align}
> show that \begin{align}2< 1/a + 1/b < \e \tag{2}\label{2}\end{align}

Hint.
From \eqref{1} there are two solutions for $b$ in terms of $a$:
\begin{align}
b=f_0(a)&=-\frac{a}{\ln(\e\cdot a)}\,\Wp\left(-\frac{\ln(\e\cdot a)}{\e\cdot a}\right)
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
b=f_1(a)&=-\frac{a}{\ln(\e\cdot a)}\,\Wm\left(-\frac{\ln(\e\cdot a)}{\e\cdot a}\right)
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}
where $\Wp$ is the principal branch
and $\Wm$ is the other real branch
of the Lambert $\W$ function.

[image]

Since the case $a=b$ must be excluded, we need to prove \eqref{2} for two cases:

\begin{align}
1)\quad a\in(\tfrac1\e,1),\quad b=f_0(a)
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
2)\quad a>1,\quad b=f_1(a)
\tag{6}\label{6}
.
\end{align}
Note that

\begin{align}
\frac11+\frac1{f_0(1)}
&=\frac11+\frac1{f_1(1)}
=2
,\\
\lim_{a\to\tfrac1\e}
\left(\frac1{a}+\frac1{f_1(a)}\right)
&=\e
,\\
\text{and }\quad
\lim_{a\to\infty}
\left(\frac1a+\frac1{f_0(a)}\right)
&=\e
\end{align}

[image]

[image]

$\endgroup$